# JQuery get the value of the newly selected/unselected element of a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am currently working on multiselect (selectpicker) and I'd like to get the value of the element that the user just selected.

Here's what I've got :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />

<select class="form-control selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="select_example">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function (){
         $(document).on('changed.bs.select', '#select_example', function(ev, picker) {
             alert($(this).val());
         });
     });
     
</script>
```

"$(this).val()" gives me the array of selected values. What I'd like to have is, for example if *1* is already selected and the user selects *2*, to know that 2 has just been selected. Or, if *1* and *2* are selected and the user unselects *2*, to know that *2* has just been unselected.

Thanks in advance !

**Update :**

Thanks to Aditya Sharma, I found a solution to my problem :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />

<select class="form-control selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="select_example">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function (){
         $(document).on('changed.bs.select', '#select_example', function(e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
             alert($('#select_example option').eq(clickedIndex).val() + "  " + isSelected);
         });
     });
     
</script>
```

Comment: See the duplicate for the solution, just change `text()` to `val()`: http://jsfiddle.net/ydz5e3a0/

Comment: You can use changed.bs.select event to do that

    jQuery('body').on("changed.bs.select", ".bootstrap-select", function(e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue){
            }
        });
Refer [documentation][1]


  [1]: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#events